# vlookup to workbook A from workbook B

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to do a vlookup in workbook A that will pull identical information from workbook B. Both workbooks are already open.

The program should be in a third workbook C.

The name of both workbooks are not the same so I give it a variable format (hence, the program should work for any workbook we set) and the range to the last record from either workbook A or B can vary.

I have an example I recorded but it doesn't work the way I want it.

In my example, I am pulling to workbook B from workbook A. I also trimmed the lookup value from workbook B because of spaces and I want it to match lookup value in workbook A (most doesn't have space, not sure about all). Is there a way trim lookup value in workbook A as well?

```
Windows("test A.xlsx").Activate
Windows("test B.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(trim(RC[-1]),'[test A.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B30000")
Range("B1:B30000").Select
Range("B1").Select
Windows("mac.xlsm").Activate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. check if it works for you. Autofill would not work properly, so it better you identify the lastrow and use with and end with option.

```
Sub vlookupexample()

Dim FileA As Workbook
Dim FileB As Workbook
Dim fileALastrow As Long
Dim FileBLastrow As Long


Set FileA = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\fileA.xlsx")
Set FileB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raja\Desktop\fileB.xlsx")

FileA.Activate

fileALastrow = FileA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

FileB.Activate

FileBLastrow = FileB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

FileA.Activate
FileA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Select
With FileA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & fileALastrow)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[fileB.xlsx]Sheet1!C1:C2,2,0)"
       .Value = .Value
        End With
Msgbox "Process Completed"
End Sub
```